# How to compare Dates in MongoDB (NodeJS + mongoose)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have some data in MongoDB and I want to Compare dates that are stored in it to be between 2 dates.
the problem is it always returns null when I use $gte or $lte in queries.

Schema:

```
const SettingSchema = new Schema({
advertisment: [
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
        ,
        fromdate: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now()
        }
        ,
        todate: {
            type: Date
        }
        ,
        active:{
            type:Boolean
        }
    }
]});
```

Sample Data:

```
{
"advertisment": [
    {
        "fromdate": "2010-06-29T06:53:32.643Z",
        "_id": "5d170b634ebf4d1848efbe9a",
        "name": "ads1",
        "todate": "2030-06-29T09:38:32.643Z",
        "active": true
    },
    {
        "fromdate": "2010-06-29T06:53:32.643Z",
        "_id": "5d170baae38bc832c4d89d9a",
        "name": "ads2",
        "todate": "2030-06-29T09:38:32.643Z",
        "active": true
    }
]
}
```

Query :

```
let currentDate = new Date();

Setting.findOne(
    {
        "advertisment.active": true,
        "advertisment.fromdate": { $gte: currentDate },
        "advertisment.todate": { $lte: currentDate },
    },
    'advertisment')
    .then(data =>
    {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

how to compare these dates in MongoDB (mongoose)?

Comment: In schema, use type as String instead of Date for fromdate & todate fields. At at the time of storing & querying   fromdate &/or todate, use new Date().toJSON() to generate date string. After doing this, your existing query will work correctly.

Comment: Another thing you can do if you dont want to go with the response above is to declare current date as 
let currentDate = new Date().toDateString();

The comparison should return the correct response this time

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
new Date().toISOString()
```

instead of

```
new Date()
```

**Try :**

```
let currentDate = new Date().toISOString();

Setting.findOne(
    {
        "advertisment.active": true,
        "advertisment.fromdate": { $gte: currentDate },
        "advertisment.todate": { $lte: currentDate },
    },
    'advertisment')
    .then(data =>
    {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

You can check the type mongo saves by default easily. Go to the mongo shell, and type in `Date()`. It's essentially `new Date().toString()` in nodejs. If you type in `new Date()` you will get ISO Date string. Similarly, `Date.now()` would give timestamp.

`Date.now()` always gives **present** timestamp in epoch seconds (UNIX time) irrespective of params passed to it. Mismatch in types causes the failure when using comparison operators.

Depending upon what type you are storing, try using `new Date().toISOString()`, or `new Date().toString()` or `Date.now()`. The sample data you provided looks like it is ISO date string.

Answer (score 1):

actually you can simply compare using `new Date()` without convert it to ISODate as mongodb does. It seems that you have to switch your fromdate's $gte to $lte and todate's $lte to $gte, because $lte means your target/docs date field need to be earlier or equal than your specified date.